# Creating DFC Client Objects is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, documentum, dfc

I would like to find out if anyone else is or has experienced this issue when using .Net & Documentum DFC.

When using .Net to Communicate with Documentum at the point of creating the DFC Client objects, it takes about 30 seconds to execute.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
            //create Client objects
            IDfClientX clientx = new DfClientX(); 
            IDfClient client = clientx.getLocalClient(); //this line takes 30+ seconds
```

This is true when using getLocalClient(); and getLocalClient32();

I've tested this code on two machines and the behavior is the same.

Comment: What versions of the DFC, Content Server, and .Net are you using?

Comment: Also, do you do this multiple times in your application, and if so, does it take 30 seconds each time?

Answer (score 0):

When you have your `dfc.properties` file configured to look for docbrokers that aren't available at run time you will experience this issue.

I didn't try to look for the source of this code but I would guess that there is some kind of timeout that needs to occur while fetching available content servers when instantiating DFC client.